# How to display the data in a specific format/layout in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have a data of more than 1000 products. Now I want to display the 3 product in one row and the 4rth product should come in next line and so. Something like the attached image.[image]

Here I am :

```
<span *ngFor= "let result of results;let i=index;">
//Logic to display result in this format 
//  X X X
//  X X X
//  ..
</span>
```

Comment: I think it's more of a css question. You can define max-width of the container.
Any specific reason for the three column arrangement? Because the web page should instead be responsive and accommodate based on screen (viewport) width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the logic below :

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i % 3 == 0" class="row">
    {{ result }}
    <div *ngIf="i + 1 < results.length">{{ results[i + 1] }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="i + 2 < results.length">{{ results[i + 2] }}</div>
  </div>
</div
```